# python nested import from subdirectory

Tags: python

```
root
├── rootfile.py
├── folder
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── file.py
│   └── subfolder
│       └── __init__.py
│       └── subfile.py
```

The folder structure is as above.

assume file has function foo(), subfile subfoo().

rootfile imports foo() from file.py by

```
from folder.file import foo
```

file imports subfoo() from subfile.py by

```
from subfolder.subfile import subfoo
```

and reports ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subfolder'.
How should I address this error? I have attempted sys.path.append in the file.py but it did not work.

Interestingly,

```
from folder.subfolder.subfile import subfoo
```

works from rootfile, but this is not what I need.

I appreciate your time and guidance in advance.

Comment: Why you cannot just use `folder.subfolder.subfile import subfoo` in the `file.py`? It is completely standard way of importing in Python.

Comment: @vahvero Good question. In the real context, rootfile and file serve different purposes, so I wanted to separate the two files.

Comment: I am not naturally sure but I think that might be partly unwise design. The import paths should generally be from the same level and doing fancy staff will lead to problems down the line.

Comment: I will take your caution. My task involves integrating multiple projects into a single pipeline, so I wanted to separate the folders for cleaner design. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your "path to look for imports" contains root of your project, but not folder/subfolder etc.

Using relative import should help:

```
   from .subfolder.subfile import subfoo
```